# What is a good way to measure how much the geometry of the fibers of a family vary

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a moduli problem and $Y\to X$ be its universal object. For the sake of concreteness, take your favourite moduli problem on curves admitting a fine moduli space $X$ and let $Y$ be its universal curve.

Now consider an isotrivial family in such moduli problem $Z\to S$, that is such that its image in the moduli space is only a point.

Then the two families, $Y\to X$ and $Z\to S$, are somehow the two extremes of some spectrum: on one side a family that varies "as much as possible", namely a moduli space, on the other a family that varies "as little as possible", namely something that is (almost) a product of a constant object by the basis.

My question is: what is a good object (geometric invariant, sheaf, or whatever this may be) that measures the complexity of the geometry of a family, locally on the basis—that is, that determines whether the family is more in the "isotrivial direction" or more in the "moduli space" direction?

I expect this to have appeared in algebraic geometry, in differential geometry, and maybe in topology as well, so it should be something quite natural, of course taking the suitable notion of "family" in every instance.

Comment: Are you asking about the rank of the Kodaira-Spencer map at a general point of the base?

Comment: I don't know the terminology, so maybe this is all correct, but do you really mean "let $X$ be a moduli *problem*" (rather than, say, "moduli space")?  Does $Z$ really live over some unspecified space $S$, rather than over $X$?

Comment: @JasonStarr maybe? I have very little knowledge of the KS map, other than it appearing in some talks sometime.

Comment: @Lspice Yes, X should be called moduli space, I used moduli problem as I see the moduli space as the "collection" of the objects in the problem rather than the "solution" to it, hence I took some liberty. I'm happy to correct if you feel like it is puzzling.

Comment: @Giulia Just to clarify Jason's comment a bit. One "measure" for how far a family is from being constant is the "differential" of the moduli map. For example, let $X\to S$ be a smooth proper curve of genus $g$. Then there is a moduli map $\phi:S\to \mathcal{M}_g$. This map literally "measures" how far you are from being the constant family. But you could also consider the map induced on tangent spaces at some point  $p\in S$ (e.g., general point): $Tan_S(p) \to Tan_{\mathcal{M}_g}(\phi(p))$. In this example $Tan_{\mathcal{M}_g}(\phi(p))  = H^1(X_p, T_{X_p})$.

Comment: One can look at the generic fiber of the family, defined over k(X), and ask what's the minimal transendence degree over k that this object can be defined. This will be zero for the constant family, and I think dim(X) for the universal family. This idea is formalized in the framework of essential dimension.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Can one see the KS map as something intrinsic to the family I am considering? I would like from any family, without "knowing" to which moduli problem it belongs, to understand how much the geometry of its fibers vary.

Comment: @Giulia Yes it is intrinsic. Let $X\to S$ be a smooth proper morphism. Let $s$ be a point in $S$.  Let $X_s$ be the fibre. Let $T = T_{S,s}$ be the tangent space of $S$ at $s$. Every element in $T$ gives an infinitesimal deformation of $X_s$; see Hartshorne's book on deformation theory or Sernesi's book on deformation theory. This defines a map $T \to H^{1}(X_s,\Theta_{X_s})$, where $\Theta_{X_s}$ is the tangent bundle of $X_s$. This is (one incarnation of) the Kodaira-Spencer map. There is no explicit mention of moduli spaces (although local deformation spaces are hidden in this discussion).

Comment: It seems to me that both KS map and essential dimension are very nice solutions. As KS is already explained in details and needs no additional job to trasform it in answer would you mind doing it so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a special, but instructive, case. Let  $A\to S$ be a family of abelian varieties over an irreducible variety, say over an algebraically closed field $k$. The *$k(S)/k$-trace of $A$* is an abelian variety $B/k$ which is, roughly speaking, the largest abelian variety defined over $k$ such that $B\otimes_k S$ is a subfamily of $A$. So $\dim(B)$ is a rough measure of the "constant-ness" of the family, and $B$ itself is a finer measure.